# How to Check Google Analytics for Location > Device > Source > Keyword?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Is it possible to check in google analytics? Just like mentioned above.

Location > Device > Source > Campaign

Example

California > mobile > Google > Best music player online

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do something like this would be to utilize segments. You could click the add segment link above the graph, then click the orange new segment button. From here, go to advanced and then select Conditions, then add in the criteria you want (see screenshot below as an example). Once you have the segment added, the reports will adjust and only show you this data about California users on mobile devices. You could then look at Google -> keywords with the segment added and the report would now only show you keywords for people in California on a mobile device.

[image]